# PHP merge 2 array then parse it to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created two functions in PHP both the function returning an array I want to merge both the array and return a JSON.

Example code:

```
function get_data($conn, $post_id) {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE Post_id='".$post_id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    global $myArray;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
    { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $Post_id = $row['Post_id'];
        $Post_title = $row['Post_title'];
        $Post_body = $row['Post_body'];
        $myArray[] = array( 'Post_id' => $Post_id, 'Post_title' => $Post_title, 'Post_body' => $Post_body );
    }
    likedislike($conn, $post_id, $myArray); }
}


function likedislike($conn, $post_id, $myArray)
{
    $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM likeunlike WHERE postid = '".$post_id."' AND likes=1";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
    global $myArray;
    global $username;
    $userlist = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
        $Usrname = $row['username'];
        $userlist[] = array( 'username' => $Usrname );
    }
    $newarray = array_merge($myArray, $userlist);
    echo json_encode($newarray);
}
```

Comment: Show the code.  What have you tried.  Hint:  read [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and understand how that behaves vs. `$mergedArray = $array1 + $array;`

Comment: there is no proble if its contain the key and value ,,, its store in variable .

Comment: Check This... https://eval.in/817282 ... For Example .. If its Contain keys and Values ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do function like this by using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
function getMergedJson($array1, $array2) {
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

With what you showed me in comment, I think you should do following, there has nothing to do with array merge:

```
function get_data($conn, $post_id) {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE Post_id='".$post_id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    global $myArray;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) { 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $Post_id = $row['Post_id'];
            $Post_title = $row['Post_title'];
            $Post_body = $row['Post_body'];
            $myArray[] = array( 'Post_id' => $Post_id, 'Post_title' => $Post_title, 'Post_body' => $Post_body, 'Username' => likedislike($conn, $post_id, $myArray); );

        }        
    }
    echo json_encode($newarray);
}

function likedislike($conn, $post_id, $myArray)
{
    $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM likeunlike WHERE postid = '".$post_id."' AND likes=1";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
    global $myArray;
    global $username;
    $userlist = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
        $Usrname = $row['username'];
        $userlist[] = array( 'username' => $Usrname );
    }
    return $userlist;
}
```

Comment: my array have a keys and values

Comment: Please show an example in your question. Your example array + the result you expected

Comment: function get_data($conn,  $post_id)
    {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE Post_id='".$post_id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    global $myArray;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $Post_id = $row['Post_id'];
     $Post_title = $row['Post_title'];
     $Post_body = $row['Post_body'];
    $myArray[] = array(
 
 'Post_id' => $Post_id,
 'Post_title' => $Post_title,
 'Post_body' => $Post_body
 
 );
    }
     likedislike($conn,  $post_id, $myArray);
        
    }
    }

Comment: function likedislike($conn,  $post_id, $myArray)
    {
     $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM likeunlike WHERE postid = '".$post_id."' AND likes=1";
        $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
        global $myArray;
     global $username;
      $userlist = array();
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
            
   $Usrname = $row['username'];
   $userlist[] = array(
   
   'username' => $Usrname
   
   );
                  
     
    }
   $newarray = array_merge($myArray, $userlist);
    echo json_encode($newarray);
    }

Comment: @JitenderSingh  ... please check my ans ... and example on it https://eval.in/817282

Comment: @JitenderSingh please accept answer if this solve your problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use first array_merge();

`$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

and then json_encode

`$json = json_encode($result);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

**array_merge**

> array_merge() function merges one or more arrays into one array.

**json_encode**

> json_encode() used to convert into json data

**Example:**

```
<?php
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
$myarray = array_merge($a1,$a2);
$json_data = json_encode($myarray );
echo json_data; 
?>
```

**Or**

**Example:** if Keys and Values

```
<?php
$a1=array("Volvo"=>"XC90","BMW"=>"X5");
$a2=array("abc"=>"XxX","xyz"=>"Xz");

$myarray = array_merge($a1,$a2);

$json_data = json_encode($myarray);
echo $json_data; 
?>
```

> For Example See This... 
>   https://eval.in/817282

Comment: that's great Rishikesh,one more quick question what is the best practice to insert element into array inside a while loop.

Comment: @Jitender..  okkzz wait i send you link with proper example... To better understand...

Comment: If it's solve your problem .. than please accept the ans.. thank you.. !!

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: my array contains keys and values

Comment: @JitenderSingh ... Please Check My Ans ,, i hope its help you , ,, for Live example visit here...  https://eval.in/817282